# How to Remove %20 from Url

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

[http://oktrad.dotdigital.pk/t/Alemán%20(Alemania)-Alemán%20(Austria)](http://oktrad.dotdigital.pk/t/Alem%C3%A1n%20(Alemania)-Alem%C3%A1n%20(Austria))
basically i want to remove %20 from url. There no any Query parameter in url. i want remove %20 to underscore '_' or same as space.
[http://oktrad.dotdigital.pk/t/Alemán](http://oktrad.dotdigital.pk/t/Alem%C3%A1n) (Alemania)-Alemán (Austria)
[http://oktrad.dotdigital.pk/t/Alemán_(Alemania)-Alemán_(Austria)](http://oktrad.dotdigital.pk/t/Alem%C3%A1n_(Alemania)-Alem%C3%A1n_(Austria))

Comment: `%20` is just a space when it's URL encoded (which is not just for query params). If you want to replace it with an underscore, you need to do that before you put it in the URL. Please show us the code that adds the string to the URL and what you've tried so far. We need to see some specifics about what you're doing where to be able to help. The question is too vague and unspecific atm.

Comment: Use https://github.com/cocur/slugify to make your link beautiful

Comment: @ShivSingh - They seem to be using Laravel, which already have helpers for doing that. No need for any third party lib (it's a good suggestion for a lib though, I tend to use that one myself :-))

Comment: There's not enough detail here to provide a decent answer. We have no clue what would work for your particular site. Please share what you already tried so we can help you based off of that

Answer (score 1):

You can use [urldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) :

```
urldecode('http://oktrad.dotdigital.pk/t/Alemán%20(Alemania)-Alemán%20(Austria)')
//output - http://oktrad.dotdigital.pk/t/Alemán (Alemania)-Alemán (Austria)
```

Or, you can use [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for convert space to `_` :

```
str_replace('%20', '_', 'http://oktrad.dotdigital.pk/t/Alemán%20(Alemania)-Alemán%20(Austria)')
//output - http://oktrad.dotdigital.pk/t/Alemán_(Alemania)-Alemán_(Austria)
```